# Make piece of code efficient for big data

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have the following code:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for i in list:
    temp = df[df["customer id"]==i]
    new_df = new_df.append(temp)
```

where `list` is a list of customer id's for the customers that meet a criteria chosen before. I use the `temp` dataframe because there are multiple rows for the same customer.

I consider that I know how to code, but I have never learnt how to code for big data efficiency. In this case, the `df` has around 3 million rows and `list` contains around 100,000 items. This code ran for more than 24h and it was still not done, so I need to ask, am I doing something terribly wrong? Is there a way to make this code more efficient?

Comment: yes, `new_df = new_df.append(temp)` is very inefficient. It makes your algorithm quadratic time, `pandas.Dataframe.append` always creates whole-new dataframe. The most efficient way would probably be to make `'customer id'` column an index and simply select with your list

Comment: I simulated with 3 million record and 100000 customer ids. It takes only a few seconds with isin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list` is a type in Python. You should avoid naming your variables with built-in types or functions. I simulated the problem with 3 million rows and a list of customer id of size 100000. It took only a few seconds using isin.

```
new_df = df[ df['customer id'].isin(customer_list) ]
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, this worked perfectly in just seconds. I didn't realize `isin` could be used this way, so thank you! The huge difference in time between the two codes still baffles me but I get it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code below, which should make things faster.

```
new_df = df.loc[df['customer id'].isin(list)]
```